# How to initialize or change values inside of an array in a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am working with a class which has an array of characters.

```
class board
{
   char spot[64];

public:
   board();
   ~board(void);


};
```

I want to set each of the values in the array to the same character when the program begins how can I initialize there values in the constructor? and is there an easy way to access and allow changes to them by their index?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this in C++03. However, it is possible to initialize arrays in a constructor initializer list in C++11:

```
board::board()
: spot { 1, 2, 1, 2, /* ... */ }
{  }
```

You can either type out the values, or come up with a magic variadic template to provide "N repeated values" (as long as the type is integral). Also, any missing elements are zero-initialized (e.g. `char spot[4] { 1, 2 };`).

For access, you use `spot[i]` inside the class, and you can write suitable accessor functions if you need to (though you should always worry if your class is just "forwarding" a member -- really you want your class to encapsulate some higher-order functionality).

If you want to see template code to "initialize an array of `N` with fixed values", perhaps you should post that as a separate question.

---

Update: Here is a naive template trick that initializes all array elements to the value `2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <prettyprint.hpp>

class Foo
{
    int arr[10];

    template <typename T, T> struct Filler { };
    template <typename T, bool, unsigned int, T...> struct FillHelper { };

    template <typename T, unsigned int I, T V, T ...Vals>
    Foo(FillHelper<T, true, I, V, Vals...>)
    : arr { V, Vals... } { }

    template <typename T, unsigned int I, T V, T ...Vals>
    Foo(FillHelper<T, false, I, V, Vals...>)
    : Foo(FillHelper<T, I == 1, I - 1, V, V, Vals...>()) { }

    template <typename T, unsigned int N, T V>
    Foo(Filler<T, V>, T const (&)[N])
    : Foo(FillHelper<T, N == 1, N - 1, V>())
    { }

public:
    Foo() : Foo(Filler<int, 2>(), arr)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo: " << arr << "\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    Foo x;
}
```

Output: `Foo: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

Comment: Would `: spot {}` zero-initialize the members like plain old `int arr[10] = {};` ?

Comment: @Kos: Yes. Also, so would `: spot()` even in C++03 (but not in C++98 :-) ).

Comment: @Chubsdad: Added! You need delegating constructor and variadic template support.

Answer (score 0):

to set  all the values in an array to a default value x, you can use something like std::fill_n
for example to set all the elements to -1 
    std::fill_n(array, 100, -1);

Answer (score 0):

> set each of the values in the array to the **same** character

Why not using memset ? For example init each of the values to 0x01

```
board::board()
{
    memset(spot, 0x01, sizeof(spot));
}
```

Comment: I have never heard of memset is it a function of the standard library?

Comment: This a very very common 'C' function : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign each element using for loop.